# 2 foreign keys referencing 1 primary key

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship, diagram, visual-paradigm

So my intention here is to make the "`Employee`" contain 2 references to the same Primary Key in the "`EmployeeContactInformation`" table. The reason for this, is I want my employee to contain 2 different copies of the same table. E.g. 1 for `work contact info`, another for `home contact info`.

How would I implement this and what relationship would I use?
I'm assuming 1 to Many?

**Current database screenshot**

[image: Current database screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets change the design of your database:

- Creat a table named as ContactInfoTypes. It will hold the definitions of each ContactInfoTypes you want (in your case: workContactInfo and homeContactInfo). It will have two columns (contactTypeId, contactTypeName)
- Add an extra column to named as ContactInfoType (DATATYPE number) in your EmployeeContactInfo TABLE. The Column ContactInfoType will hold a `Foreign-Key` value of above TABLE ContactInfoTypes

When you insert a contact in TABLE: EmployeeContactInfo, you would have to `Insert` two rows (one with the number value stored against workContactInfo and one with the homeContactInfo).

Answer (score 0):

1. Employee can have several contact Infos ( home and work like you mentioned). So therefore the relationship should be one to many
2. To model this you should add a foreign key of the one side of the relationship into the many side . Therefore you should add an employee_id column in the EmployeeContact table. This way each employee contact row will be connected to an employee
3. "Work extension" column in the employee table can be moved to the EmployeeContact table and renamed "extension" since it is a phone number extension that could be for a home phone or work phone
4. "Home phone number " column in the EmployeeContact table should be renamed to just "phone number" because the table is for both home and work
5. Should save another column in the EmployeeContact table which saves information about work/home

Comment: I have implemented your comments and they are fine. However, my system  will work by accessing the employee, then you will be able to select the type of contact information. With the answer you provided. Will this be possible?

Comment: You can use a query such as this to access the employee contact info if you have an employeeId    <code>  Select * From employee_contact_info where employee_id = ? </code>  You should pass the employeeId where the question mark is

Comment: let me know if you are looking for something else